# Is it possible to execute code even after the program exits the main()

Tags: multithreading, process, control-flow

Is there any possibility to execute code even after the program exits the main() method?

Comment: why don't you provide us with a concrete code example of what you'd like to accomplish?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to throw in all those languages.

Comment: What makes you think such a thing is possible?

Comment: I agree with Matteo - this would not be a bad question if it was just for one language but including four language tags just makes it four different questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C and C++, functions registered through [atexit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) can be called after `main()` returns.

In C++, [static destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278441/static-destructor) can also be called after `main()` returns.

Comment: I voted you up, as I meant to post the same. But to be technical, aren't registered atexit calls executed before main returns - right before, that is?

Comment: @gnometorule, how would the program know that `main()` *is about to return*? It makes more sense to wait for it to return, then act accordingly (since the runtime code is the one calling `main()` in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It was an actual question. I visualized the exit sys call to call registered atexit functions, if any, in which case the exit call proper would return after them.

Comment: Ah, that's not the same thing. If `exit()` is called, `main()` never returns (since `exit()` itself does not return). I was thinking of the other case, returning from `main()` without calling `exit()`.

Comment: +1 for the static dtors.  Similarly, static ctors run before main is called..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some other thread can continue working after program exits main(), so I can say Yes!

```
public class Main extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Main());
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("main is exiting");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("thread is running");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: unless it is a background thread, it which case it will terminate.

Comment: No, _all_ threads stop when you call `exit(3)`. This is why there is `pthread_exit(3)`, which allows to terminate only one thread.

Comment: I can provide an example with java(in 5-10 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Yes for C#: Finalizers of objects that go out of scope only after main() has exited will be executed afterwards.

This does come in handy sometimes, e.g. to remove lockfiles

Answer (score 1):

C++: sure. Just put it into the destructor of a global object, and it will be run after `main` returns (but keep in mind that there's no guarantee that any global object is still constructed).

(... although, the trick is that the "real" entrypoint of the executable usually is not your `main`, but another function that initializes globals, calls your main and when it returns it destroys them before terminating)

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility you have is `fork()`, and `exit()` in the parent. There is no other way around that. Threads won't help.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, there's [atexit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit), which will call a function during "normal" termination.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. But you can always start a new thread at the end of the main and it will execute even after the main has completed.

Comment: I won't, the main method will wait for the thread to stop.  If it was a daemon thread it will be terminated.

Comment: I disagree. Try this: **public class TestMain{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main start");
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    
                }
            }
        }).start();
        System.out.println("main end");
    }      
}** What I can see, "main end" is beeing printed which should mean the main method has completed.

Comment: I disagree. The JVM stops just before the return on the main method, waiting for the other threads to complete.  It will therefore execute all statements in the main method, but the program will not terminate yet.

Comment: Could you show my a link from Oracle/Sun where it says so?

Comment: @JacoVanNiekerk : Even if you debug the program you can see that the main thread has completed and that the other thread is the only running! So I am sorry, I still think the main method completes unless you can prove I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can create a new `Thread` and set `IsBackground` to false. `Main` will exit but the .NET Framework will keep your your application doing whatever it needs to be doing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread WriteLine");
    });

    thread.IsBackground = false;
    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Main WriteLine");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible.  When the main method exists, the program terminates.